# TCL/TK How to define floating point precision in scientific notation

Tags: floating-point, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I set, in TCL the precision for a floating point expressed in the scientific format?
I need to set at maximum a width of 8 character.

```
set number 1.57766e-06
puts $Output "[format "%-.7e" $number]"
```

it doesn't work for me because I obtain:

```
1.5776600e-006
```

but I would obtain:

```
1.58e-06
```

I want just 2 digits for the exponential term.

Comment: `regsub {0(..)$} $data {\1} data` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK one can't specify the number of digits in the exponent. A workaround is to format both parts individually:

```
lassign [split $number e] mantissa exponent
set number [format %.2f $mantissa]e[format %+03d $exponent]
```

This command can format both numbers with and without exponent part:

(**edit** instead of testing and replacing the exponent, one can ensure that there is an exponent part.)

```
proc fmtnum number {
    lassign [split [format %.2e $number] e] mantissa exponent
    return ${mantissa}e[format %+03d $exponent]
}
```

Documentation: [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: this doesn't work for me: - expected integer but got "" -

Comment: It works only for numbers that have an exponent part. For numbers that don't, you get that error. I'll post a fix later -- it's just a question of testing the exponent before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The `format` command doesn't give you control over the number of exponent digits, but I can get the result you want anyway by using a different format:

```
% set number 1.57766e-06
1.57766e-06
% format %.2e $number
1.58e-06
```

I find it can help to experiment in an interactive shell when picking complex formats.

Comment: i tried this script with " %.2e" and the result is still the same with 3 digits for the exponential part :/ it reduces just only the decimal part.